# Removing an image source after x seconds

Tags: wpf, multithreading

I have a WPF application that will set an image source when a button is clicked
I want to then clear the image source after so many seconds, say 15 seconds have passed.
How can I do this?
I have tried to use Thread.sleep but it clears the source right away then just pauses the application for the 15 seconds

here is what i have for that method

```
 private void btnCapture_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {  
    imgCapture.Source = //my image source;

    Thread.Sleep(15000);
    imgCapture.Source = null;

 }
```

I have also tried

```
 private void btnCapture_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {  
    imgCapture.Source = //my image source;


    imgCapture.Source = null;
     Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(clearSource));
        thread.Start();

  }

    private void clearSource()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(15000);
        imgCapture.Source = null;
    }
```

but I get an  error saying The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
How can I get that image source to clear after 15 seconds. 
Thanks!

Comment: 30000 is three seconds so you should be setting it to 150000

Comment: The milliseconds are not the issue 15000 or 150000 is irrelevant as it still doesn't work for any amount of time.

Comment: 30000 milliseconds is three seconds? That's new to me, thanks for the update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx):

```
DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15) };

    // in constructor
    timer.Tick += OnTimerTick;

private void btnCapture_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    imgCapture.Source = //my image source;
    timer.Start();
}

private void OnTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer.Stop();
    imgCapture.Source = null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Will this cause any issues if the application is running for an entire day with many clicks of that button? Will I need to dispose the timer or will all be ok?

Comment: No, you may only reset/restart the timer if the button is clicked before the 15 seconds are over :-) No need to dispose since you are only using one timer object all the time.

Answer (score 0):

@Clemens answer is fine, but to satisfy my recent [RX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx) fetish:

```
void btnCapture_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    imgCapture.Source = //my image source;
    Observable.Interval( TimeSpan.FromSeconds( 15 ) ).TimeInterval().Subscribe( _ => imgCapture.Source = null );
}
```

Comment: Nice, I have been hearing some RX buzz. Guess I should check it out as well.Thanks